# POST contents of a html to REST api ,and GET response from the webservice

Tags: java, html, rest, http-post, http-get

I'm new to the rest service.
My doubt is, I have an html form and it contains data, for example this:

[image: THIS IS THE HTML CODE]

After entering the username, password, etc. fields data and selecting the item from checkbox, all the selected and entered inputs, after clicking the submit `button` must pass to the REST SERVICE API. The response should be in HTML format.

How could I do this?

Comment: Why you want HTML as output ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your code as **text** and mark it as code-block, that other people can copy-paste it.

Answer (score -1):

You should collect form data via a javascript function to send it to a rest api with POST method. Please find a sample in below;

```
<html>    
  <head>    
    <script src="jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script>
    function createProfile()
    {
        data = $("#registrationForm").serializeArray(); 
        $.ajax({
            url:         'http://localhost:8080/profiles',
            method:      'POST',
            dataType:    'text', //You can also define this as Json
            data:         data,
            success:      function() { /*doSomething();*/ },
            error:        function(error) {/*doSomething();*/}
        });
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="createProfile()" id="registrationForm">
        Name   : <input type="text" name="name" /> <br />
        Surname: <input type="text" name="surname" /> <br /> 
        Age    : <input type="text" name="age" /> <br /> 
                 <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Just try and change form elements as you required..